# Looking for the most efficient select query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a table and need the result over different lines where different key values in one column must exist.

I'm getting this table once a day via REST API from another system and looks in my MySQL DB like this (simplfied):

```
+----+------+------------+-------+
| ID | type | date       | value |
+----+------+------------+-------+
|  1 | A    | 2019-06-01 |     1 |
|  2 | B    | 2019-06-01 |     2 |
|  3 | A    | 2019-06-02 |     4 |
|  4 | B    | 2019-06-03 |     5 |
|  9 | A    | 2019-06-09 |    11 |
| 10 | B    | 2019-06-09 |    14 |
| 11 | A    | 2019-06-24 |    99 |
+----+------+------------+-------+
```

Now, I need a select which results all only where a value exists for type A and type B at the same date. The result should look like this:

```
+------------+-------+--------+----+------+------------+-------+
| date       | typeA | valueA | ID | type | date       | value |
+------------+-------+--------+----+------+------------+-------+
| 2019-06-01 | A     |      1 |  2 | B    | 2019-06-01 |     2 |
| 2019-06-09 | A     |     11 | 10 | B    | 2019-06-09 |    14 |
+------------+-------+--------+----+------+------------+-------+
```

- First idea:

Using subselects... probably bad idea for large tables... but I'm not sure.

```
SELECT * from 
(SELECT date as dateA, value as valueA from V1 where type = 'A') AS subA,
(SELECT date as dateB, value as valueB from V1 where type = 'B') AS subB
WHERE dateA = dateB
```

- 2nd idea:

Creating two temporary tables and then to a join. But needs time to create two tables and the the join over both new temporary tables.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY table tA SELECT date, type as typeA, value as valueA from V1 WHERE type = 'A';
CREATE TEMPORARY table tB SELECT date, type as typeB, value as valueB from V1 WHERE type = 'B';

SELECT * from tA 
INNER JOIN tB on tA.date = tB.date;
```

- 3rd idea:

Creating only on temporary table and use this for a join using the main table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY table tB SELECT * from V1 WHERE type = 'B';

SELECT * from V1 
INNER JOIN tB on V1.date = tB.date
where V1.type = 'A'
```

Which of my ideas is the best for a large table or is there a better solution.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Ideally we need output off `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` as we need to know datatypes and indexes to give you the most effcient select query possible for your existing structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a self inner join

```
select select v1.date,v1.type as typeA, v1.value as valueA, 
       v2.id, v2.type as typeB, v2.date, v2.value
  from v v1 join v v2    -- v is table name
    on v1.date = v2.date
    and v1.type = 'A' and v2.type = 'B';

+------------+-------+--------+----+------+------------+-------+
| date       | typeA | valueA | ID | type | date       | value |
+------------+-------+--------+----+------+------------+-------+
| 2019-06-01 | A     |      1 |  2 | B    | 2019-06-01 |     2 |
| 2019-06-09 | A     |     11 | 10 | B    | 2019-06-09 |    14 |
+------------+-------+--------+----+------+------------+-------+
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=c0818bc58a02e0a02f7bf1aa0812df1b)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

an efficent way could be based on a inner join between the date with distinct count = 2 and the table itesel one time for ype A and one tyme for type b

```
    select t.date, t1.type typeA, t1.value valueA, t2.type typeB, t2.value valueB, 
    from (
        select  date
        from  my_table  
        group by  date  
        having count(distinct type) = 2
    ) t 
    inner join  my_table t1 on t1.date = t.date and type='A'
    inner join  my_table t2 on t2.date = t.date and type='B'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe not the most obvious query to write. 
But it can make sense as your are pivotting on a date and merging the types with a date. 
 
The performance would be very depended on the used index(es) which are unknown.

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM (

  SELECT 
     date
   , MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'A' THEN type END) AS  typeA
   , MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'A' THEN value END) AS  valueA
  FROM 
   your_table
  WHERE
   type = 'A' 
  GROUP BY 
   date  
) AS a_type 
INNER JOIN (

  SELECT 
     date
   , MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'B' THEN type END) AS  typeB
   , MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'B' THEN value END) AS  valueB  
  FROM 
   your_table
  WHERE
   type = 'B' 
  GROUP BY 
   date   
) AS b_type
ON
 a_type.date = b_type.date
```

**Result**

```
| date       | typeA | valueA | date       | typeB | valueB |
| ---------- | ----- | ------ | ---------- | ----- | ------ |
| 2019-06-01 | A     | 1      | 2019-06-01 | B     | 2      |
| 2019-06-09 | A     | 11     | 2019-06-09 | B     | 14     |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/so9kijAyDa1DKWNKLf3LEe/0)

Comment: Multiple derived tables is likely to be very inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

If each date can only have one of each type (i.e. there can't be 2 'A' or 2 'B' for the same date), then you can group by the date and use conditional aggregation to get the values for the different types.

```
select
    date,
    max(case when type = 'A' then id end) idA,
    max(case when type = 'A' then value end) valueA,
    max(case when type = 'B' then id end) idB,
    max(case when type = 'B' then value end) valueB
from V1
where type in ('A', 'B') -- only necessary if other types exist
group by date
having count(distinct type) = 2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69b9f/1